# Postgresql Functions - Using VARIADIC arguments of text type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, amazon-rds, dynamic-sql, variadic-functions

I am trying to write a function to get the list of objects in schema from Redshift. I have created a dblink from RDS PostgreSQL to Redshift. The query is working just fine when invoked individually, but not working when written inside a function with arguments. I want to pass multiple arguments (schema names), hence I used VARIADIC arguments. The function looks like below -

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_fetch_tables(VARIADIC list text[]) 
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
    DECLARE
        begin_time TIMESTAMP;
        expire_time TIMESTAMP;
    BEGIN   
        /* To fetch the list of all objects from Redshift */
        EXECUTE 'drop table if exists tmp_rs_obj_list;
        create table tmp_rs_obj_list as 
        SELECT * FROM dblink(''rs_link'',$REDSHIFT$ select * from (select schemaname, 
        tablename from pg_tables UNION select schemaname, viewname from pg_views) where schemaname 
        not in (array_to_string($1,'','')) $REDSHIFT$) AS t1 (schema_nm varchar(30), obj_nm varchar(100))' using list;
    END;
  $$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

The function compiles fine and is created successfully, but I am not able to figure out a way to call it -

Used these calls so far, without any luck -

1. select f_fetch_tables('{public,pg_catalog}')

   ERROR: there is no parameter $1
   Where: Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not 
   execute query.
2. select * from f_fetch_tables(VARIADIC '{public,pg_catalog}')

   ERROR: there is no parameter $1
   Where: Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thank you,
Kamlesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your function. I would suggest to use:

- the function `format()` for easy passing the parameter,
- dollar quoted `($fmt$)` queries inside `execute`,
- `<> all(array)` instead of `not in` operator (you do not have to convert an array to string).

The function with the suggested changes:

```
create or replace function f_fetch_tables(variadic list text[]) 
returns void
as $$
    declare
        begin_time timestamp;
        expire_time timestamp;
    begin   
        /* to fetch the list of all objects from redshift */
        execute format($fmt$
            drop table if exists tmp_rs_obj_list;
            create table tmp_rs_obj_list as 
                select * 
                from dblink(
                    'rs_link', $redshift$ 
                        select * 
                        from (
                            select schemaname, tablename 
                            from pg_tables 
                            union 
                            select schemaname, viewname 
                            from pg_views) s
                        where schemaname <> all(%L)
                    $redshift$) 
                    as t1 (schema_nm varchar(30), obj_nm varchar(100))
            $fmt$, list);
    end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Note also the proper way of passing arguments to a function with variadic parameter:

```
select f_fetch_tables('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
select * from tmp_rs_obj_list;
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to variadic parameters - same behave you will get if you use normal parameters too. It is related to dynamic SQL - the queries executed by `EXECUTE` command from PLpgSQL has own parameter's environment. So you cannot to use variables or param references from function's environment.

This code doesn't work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fx(a int)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.a = $1';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In this case, there was not passed any parameter to executed query. `$1` is not valid. You should to use a `USING` clause, when you would to pass some parameters to dynamic SQL.

This code should to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fx(a int)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foo.a = $1' USING a;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But it doesn't to solve your problem too, because you are using `USING` clause. But you are use USING clause only on level `EXECUTE` command - not on `dblink` level - where it is not supported. `dblink` API has not nothing similar to `USING` clause of `EXECUTE` command. So you have to build native SQL string with unpacked (preevaluated) parameters before you will sent it to dblink API.

You are using two levels of dynamic SQL

- `EXECUTE`

  - `dblink`

`dblink` doesn't support query parametrization - so you should not to use parameter place holders there .. $x.

In this case is better to serialize a input array to string in top plpgsql level and pass this string like dynamic SQL parameter.

```
DECLARE serialized_params text;
BEGIN
  serialized_params = (SELECT array_agg(quote_literal(quote_ident(v))) FROM unnest(ARRAY['A','b']) g(v));
  EXECUTE ' ....' USING serialized_params;
END
```